# Accessing content of custom react component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a custom react component, `menuItem`

```
var MenuItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.props.targetPath}>
        <View style={styles.menuItem}>
          <Text>{this.props.txt}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
});
```

which I use like this:

```
<MenuItem txt='MyHome' targetPath={this.home} />
```

However, it I would like to use it as follows:

```
<MenuItem targetPath={this.home}>MyHome</MenuItem>
```

so it mimics more closely an html tag. How do I achieve this?

i.e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your component implementation to this

```
var MenuItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.props.targetPath}>
        <View style={styles.menuItem}>
          <Text>{this.props.children}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
});
```

Whatever you put between JSX tags is passed as `children` prop.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but when I try to use it as shown above, I get an 'expected closing JSX tag' error, and my linter is not recognising the </MenuItem> as a closing tag.

Comment: Because you have a '/' too many at the end of your opening tag.

Comment: Man, you have `/>` right before `MyHome` string. Use it this way `<MenuItem targetPath={this.home}>MyHome</MenuItem>`

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected the question so it does not confuse other and selected your answer.